# Images appearing in all browsers but firefox

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I have a website that displays fine in chrome but not in Firefox.

This is chrome:

[image]

This is Firefox:

[image]

Three of the four main images are missing - oddly the 4th one displays fine, despite having identical code. the inspector shows the images are downloading successfully:

[image]

I have also cleared the caches, updated Firefox, etc., to no avail.

In response to the queries:

All images are served from digital ocean, not locally.

This is the css and html for the learn image and the smile image, of which the smile image appears in FF while the learn button doesn't:

CSS

> ```
>     .four_box {
>         position: absolute;
>     }
>
>     .four_btn {
>         cursor: pointer;
>         transition: all .7s;
>     }
>
>     .four_label_anchor {
>         display: flex;
>         flex-direction: column;
>         justify-content: center;
>         align-items: center;
>         position: absolute;
>         top: 0;
>         left: 0;
>         pointer-events: none;
>     }
>
>     .smile_size {
>         height: 262px;
>         width: 326px;
>     }
>
>     .learn_size {
>         height: 263px;
>         width: 183px;
>     }
> ```

HTML

```
<div id="learn" class="learn_size four_box" style="top: 437px; left: 771px;">
    <img id="learn_btn" class="learn_size four_btn" style="
     background: url(/static/img/swirl_home/chalk-btn.png);"
     onclick="animHome(this.id);">

    <div class="learn_size four_label_anchor">
        <div id="learn_label" class="four_label">Learn</div>
            <button id="learn_return" class="btn_href return_btn">
                return
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

<div id="smile" class="smile_size four_box" style="top: 438px; left:     954px;">

   <img id="smile_btn" class="smile_size center four_btn" style="
        background: url(/static/img/swirl_home/bird-btn.png);"
        onclick="animHome(this.id); homeSnapshots();">

   <div class="smile_size four_label_anchor">

       <div id="smile_label" class="four_label">Smile</div>
            <button id="smile_return" class="btn_href return_btn">
                return
            </button>

       </div>
 </div>
```

I will reread the Firefox link

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle with the code displaying the images ? Did you also cleared Chrome cache, or viewed your website in Chrome incognito mode? It's better to compare with the same situation for the 2 browsers...

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying local images, can be the problem.

Use `/` instead of `\` in the images URL will solve the problem

Otherwise, Mozilla has a general help page for such problem : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-problems-images-not-show

Comment: This does not do it.